# How to divide larger number by smaller

Tags: java

I am trying to divide the larger number in this problem by the smaller number and print the answer in a quotient form. I have done the code to where it will print the correct answer, but I am wondering how to divide the larger by smaller number. Do I use an if statement?

```
case 1:
    int number1;
    int number2;

    System.out.println("Please enter your first number");
    number1 = s.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter your second number");
    number2 = s.nextInt();

    int quotient = number1 / number2;
    int remainder = number1 % number2;  

    if(number1 > number2 || number2 > number1) {
        System.out.println("Quotient = " + quotient + "r" + remainder);
    }

    break;
```

Comment: "_how to divide the larger by smaller number_" The same as you would divide anything `x / y`. Is the actual issue figuring out which number is larger? That's just `if (x > y)` then x is larger or `if (y > x)` then y is larger. Please give more detail on what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Also, `if(number1 > number2 || number2 > number1)` will always be true unless the numbers are equal - not sure if that's what you wanted.

Comment: Im trying to divide two numbers and put it in quotient form. The problem is I always need to divide by the larger number because I cannot assume they are always entered correctly. Where and how would I enter this code?

Comment: Where? Right before you do the division. How? That's just asking us to write code for you. I have already described exactly what you need to do.

Comment: oh okay sorry. I was confused for a minute but I understand what to do. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @confused now that you're no longer confused you should change your username ;)

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like that:

```
int smallerNumber;
int biggerNumber;

System.out.println("Please enter your first number");
smallerNumber = s.nextInt();


int temp;
System.out.println("Please enter your second number");
temp =  s.nextInt();

smallerNumber=Math.min(temp,smallerNumber);
biggerNumber=Math.max(temp,smallerNumber);
```

Or using array and then sort it:

```
List<Integer> arr= new ArrayList<>(2);

System.out.println("Please enter your first number");
arr.add( s.nextInt());


System.out.println("Please enter your second number");
arr.add( s.nextInt());

Collections.sort(arr);

//now arr.get(0) is smaller and arr.get(1) is bigger
```